# Can I delete a server using discord.js or discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, discord.js

I want to use the bot to delete the server.
I've been searching, but I don't know.

Comment: why did you need delete a server ?
If it's not your, it's clearly an attempt at malicious action.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```js
__proto__.server.delete({report:boolean, reason:"string", rate:number, prototype:{Object}, other:[Donkey Button Object]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the async discord.py coroutine is [`Client.delete_server`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_server).  The account doing the deletion must be the server owner.

The equivalent coroutine from the rewrite branch is [`Guild.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.delete), which has the same limitations.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js you can use [`Guild.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=delete).
Please note that you will have to use the guild's owner account (a user account), and that could get you banned from Discord since self-bots aren't allowed ([offical post about it](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)). So, if you want to follow the rules, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible, deleting the server would require the bot to be the server owner. The only way this would be possible is with the Guild Owner running a self-bot, which is against the TOS.